# How to execute conditional script when on new customize.php (Theme Customize) screen

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

The new "Customize" theme screen is a welcome addition in WordPress 3.4, however, I find it conflicts with my method of loading scripts loaded in the footer:

In functions.php

```
if(!is_admin())
{
/* GET PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
*************************************************************/
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions_public.php');
}
```

In functions_public.php

```
/* Move scripts to the footer, speeding up page loading time as per http://yhoo.it/IAL94Z
*************************************************************************/
if ( isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'customize.php') echo "in customize.php"; else echo "NOT in customize.php";

if(!get_option('my_scripts_head')){
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
}
```

This code branch moves those scripts from wp_head to wp_footer. When this option (my_scripts_head) is enabled, the "Customize" screen shows my theme preview without the scripts that are loaded in the footer.

I find that when I disable this option, the "Customize" screen loads fine, including my scripts.

When themes are previewed in customize.php, does wp_footer not fire?

Comment: Can we see the complete callback, as well as the `add_action()` call you're using to hook that callback?

Comment: I've pasted everything involved in the method. It checks the option setting and runs the code branch accordingly. There's no custom callback. It just moves scripts from wp_head to wp_footer. Perhaps wp_footer is not needed and thus not called on customize.php?

Comment: "*I've pasted everything involved in the method.*" - Where does this code reside? Is it just sitting, naked, in `functions.php`? If so, **that's your first problem**.

Comment: No, its in a php script that's called only on when the theme is on the public view.

Comment: "*its in a php script that's called only on when the theme is on the public view*" - How does that script get called? Where is the hook? What is the conditional? We need to see *that* code, too.

Comment: Thanks Chip. I've updated the question to include more details...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, first, let's set things up properly, with a **callback** hooked into an appropriate **action hook**:

```
<?php
function wpse55227_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Enqueue code goes here
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse55227_enqueue_scripts' );
?>
```

We'll put all of our code in to this callback.

The next step is to add our `if ( ! is_admin() )` conditional wrapper:

```
<?php
function wpse55227_enqueue_scripts() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        // Enqueue code goes here
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse55227_enqueue_scripts' );
?>
```

Now, let's add in your original code:

```
<?php
function wpse55227_enqueue_scripts() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if(!get_option('my_scripts_head')){
            remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
            remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
            remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
            add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
            add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
            add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse55227_enqueue_scripts' );
?>
```

So, at this point, we should be back to where you were before. Now, let's account for the Customizer. The easiest way is to check for the `$wp_customize` global being set:

```
<?php
function wpse55227_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Globalize
    global $wp_customize;
    // If $wp_customize is set, return
    if ( isset( $wp_customize ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if(!get_option('my_scripts_head')){
            remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
            remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
            remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
            add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
            add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
            add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse55227_enqueue_scripts' );
?>
```

By the way: out of curiosity, why are you moving all of the script enqueueing to the footer? I would imagine that has a very high likelihood of breaking things, and/or causing unintended consequences.

Comment: WordPress 4.0 introduced the conditional `is_customize_preview()`, makes things a little easier.