# Way to check if we are in Theme Customizer mode?

Tags: conditional-tags, theme-customizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute conditional script when on new customize.php (Theme Customize) screen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55227/how-to-execute-conditional-script-when-on-new-customize-php-theme-customize-sc)

Is there a Conditional Tag, or any other method, that we can use to check if we are customizing the theme?

I want to include some extra stylesheet while customizing the theme.

so I'd like to have sth like:

```
if ( theme-customizer-is-active ) {
    // load some extra styles
}
```

Comment: Don't understand this question at all. How are you defining "customizing the theme"

Comment: I mean the new feature by wordpress 3.4. "theme customizer".

Comment: But I already resolved it by this Question:
[link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55227/how-to-execute-conditional-script-when-on-new-customize-php-theme-customize-sc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As in this question: [How to execute conditional script when on new customize.php (Theme Customize) screen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55227/how-to-execute-conditional-script-when-on-new-customize-php-theme-customize-sc)

```
global $wp_customize;
if ( isset( $wp_customize ) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: The conditional `is_customize_preview()` can be used since WordPress 4.0

Comment: Link to [is_customize_preview();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_customize_preview)